# Problem with triple NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I am a new to Mathematica. I want to calculate a triple integral but Mathematica returned `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`.

Could you please help me? I attached my code here.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Ri = 10.5/10^3; 
Ro = 11.5/10^3; 
h = 1/10^3; 
c = 30/10^3; 
l = 3/10^3; 
μ = (4*Pi)/10^7; 
i0 = 1; 
f = 0.159*10^9; 
ω = 2*Pi*f; 
σ = 1; 
Subscript[Λ, 2] = Sqrt[γ^2 + I*ω*μ*σ]; 
ℒ = ((μ*Pi)/(h*(Ri - Ro))^2)*NIntegrate[(r*BesselJ[1, γ*r])*
     (R0*BesselJ[1, γ*R0])*((1 - E^((-h)*γ))^2/(E^(2*l*γ)*γ^2))*
     ((E^(2*c*γ + 2*(c + 2*h + l)*Subscript[Λ, 2])*
       (-1 + E^(2*c*Subscript[Λ, 2]))*(γ - Subscript[Λ, 2])*
       (γ + Subscript[Λ, 2])*
       ((-(E^(2*(2*h + l)*γ) + E^(2*c*Subscript[Λ, 2])))*
         (γ - Subscript[Λ, 2])^2 + 
        (1 + E^(4*h*γ + 2*l*γ + 2*c*Subscript[Λ, 2]))*(γ + Subscript[Λ, 2])^
          2))/(E^(2*(c + 2*h + l)*(γ + Subscript[Λ, 2]))*
        (γ - Subscript[Λ, 2])^4 + 
       E^(2*(c + 2*h + l)*γ + 2*(3*c + 2*h + l)*Subscript[Λ, 2])*
        (γ + Subscript[Λ, 2])^4 - E^(2*c*γ + 2*(c + 2*h + l)*Subscript[Λ, 2])*
        (2*E^(4*h*γ + 2*l*γ + 2*c*Subscript[Λ, 2]) + 
         (-1 + E^(2*c*Subscript[Λ, 2]))^2)*(γ^2 - Subscript[Λ, 2]^2)^2)), 
    {γ, 0, Infinity}, {r, Ri, Ro}, {R0, Ri, Ro}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please attach code as text, not pictures. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have followed your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some of the option values -- is this a result you expect:

```
Ri = 10.5/10^3;
Ro = 11.5/10^3;
h = 1/10^3;
c = 30/10^3;
l = 3/10^3;
\[Mu] = (4*Pi)/10^7;
i0 = 1;
f = 0.159*10^9;
\[Omega] = 2*Pi*f;
\[Sigma] = 1;

L2 = Sqrt[\[Gamma]^2 + I*\[Omega]*\[Mu]*\[Sigma]];

\[ScriptCapitalL] = ((\[Mu]*Pi)/(h*(Ri - Ro))^2)*
  NIntegrate[(r*BesselJ[1, \[Gamma]*r])*(R0*
      BesselJ[1, \[Gamma]*
        R0])*((1 - 
         E^((-h)*\[Gamma]))^2/(E^(2*
           l*\[Gamma])*\[Gamma]^2))*((E^(2*c*\[Gamma] + 
           2*(c + 2*h + l)*L2)*(-1 + E^(2*c*L2))*(\[Gamma] - 
          L2)*(\[Gamma] + 
          L2)*((-(E^(2*(2*h + l)*\[Gamma]) + E^(2*c*L2)))*(\[Gamma] - 
              L2)^2 + (1 + 
             E^(4*h*\[Gamma] + 2*l*\[Gamma] + 2*c*L2))*(\[Gamma] + 
              L2)^2))/(E^(2*(c + 2*h + l)*(\[Gamma] + L2))*(\[Gamma] -
             L2)^4 + 
        E^(2*(c + 2*h + l)*\[Gamma] + 
            2*(3*c + 2*h + l)*L2)*(\[Gamma] + L2)^4 - 
        E^(2*c*\[Gamma] + 2*(c + 2*h + l)*L2)*(2*
            E^(4*h*\[Gamma] + 2*l*\[Gamma] + 2*c*L2) + (-1 + 
              E^(2*c*L2))^2)*(\[Gamma]^2 - L2^2)^2)), {\[Gamma], 0, 
    Infinity}, {r, Ri, Ro}, {R0, Ri, Ro}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
   Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

(* -6.75294*10^-11 - 2.90231*10^-10 I *)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I don't know yet but at least it works. I tried to test it with Matlab but Matlab returned me singularity.

Comment: @Shan Ok, good luck with your work!